# SetWindowText with a String and Integer

Tags: c++

I'm running a threaded application and monitoring the duration with chrono.

What I'm trying to do is then set the window title to say "Duration: " + the time taken.

This is what I have so far but it just makes the window title blank.

```
// Calculate Duration
int duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();

// Update the window title
std::string windowText = "Duration: " + duration;
SetWindowText(_hwnd, (LPCWSTR)windowText.c_str());
```

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings. Your compiler might catch this bogus pointer arithmetic. You cannot get the result you expect by adding an integer to a string literal. All that does is advance the pointer, potentially past the end of the literal resulting in undefined behavior. Try `std::string("Duration: ") + std::to_string(duration)` or look into [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

Comment: `std::string windowText = "Duration: " + std::to_string(duration);
SetWindowText(_hwnd, CString(windowText.c_str());`

Comment: Did you include the following lines above?
`#include <chrono>`
`using namespace std::chrono;`
`auto begin = high_resolution_clock::now();`
// timed code
`auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();`

Comment: @OP `(LPCWSTR)windowText.c_str()` -- You should at all costs avoid doing any casting of a string type.  If you removed `(LPCWSTR)`, you will get a compiler error.  That error is telling you that you're doing something wrong.  By casting, you told the compiler to "shut up, I know what I'm doing".  When it comes to string types, you must provide the type that the function requires, or call a function that takes the string type *without needing to cast*.  In your case, it would have been `SetWindowTextA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's an issue where you're using pointer arithmetic and expecting string concatenation plus integer-to-string conversion.

The value `"Duration: " + duration` is going to be a pointer that is offset from the start of the `"Duration: "` string literal by `duration` bytes. If that is any value outside the range [0,10] then you'll have undefined behavior. In any case, that's not what you're looking for.

You can instead do this:

```
std::string windowText = "Duration: " + std::to_string(duration);
```

Second, you also have a problem with the call to `SetWindowText` which requires a wide string. You are attempting to cast it, but that is invalid. No character conversion takes place. You need to convert the string, OR just use wide strings to begin with:

```
std::wstring windowText = L"Duration: " + std::to_wstring(duration);
SetWindowText(_hwnd, windowText.c_str());
```

Comment: Thank-you, I was unaware about wide strings.